# How can I run xmonad on a nomachine remote desktop?

Tags: haskell, remote-desktop, gnome, xmonad, nomachine

I'm trying to configure a NoMachine remote desktop to run xmonad. One thing I keep running into is that the default xmonad [installation instructions](http://www.howtogeek.com/114728/how-to-use-xmonad-a-tiling-window-manager-for-linux/) require logging out and logging back in. In a remote desktop app like NoMachine, there's no way to log out as a user -- only disconnect from the session.

I have the option to create a new Gnome, KDM, or XDM desktop, or a custom session which can do things like run a default X client script, or a custom command at startup.

Does anyone have experience with how best to configure this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to just run a plain `xmonad` session (and not, for example, use `xmonad` as the window manager of, say, GNOME), then it should suffie to use the option of running a custom command at startup, and simply make that command `xmonad`.